# Verizon wireless router is pinging my web server - is this ok or bad?

Tags: apache, wireless, routing

So I'm working from a local cafe, doing some web development, and need to see something in my Apache's access log. And to my surprise, in the log I see, every 30 seconds or so, a request for my root web page, coming from 192.168.1.1 -- the cafe's Verizon router.

Is this a normal or known behavior? Or is it Bad?

The web server is running on my laptop, which is physically in the cafe with me. The server is supposedly private -- there's no public website or public IP address. I just use it for testing and development. I can't think of any well-intentioned reason for someone, let alone some bot running on, or via, a wi-fi router, to be asking for /index.html every 30 seconds. Or is every public wi-fi hotspot router asking every end-user for access to port 80?

Comment: Where is this web server hosted? Locally, or on a remote network?

Comment: In this a test web server deployed on your machine? and 192.168.1.1 is probably a gateway address for the cafe's network

Comment: When I work from the cafe, my apache log shows lines like this: `"192.168.1.1",20140110130115,200,"-","text/html", "/index.html","-","-"` about every 30-60 seconds. This strikes me as rather strange -- does this look like a probe of some kind, or is it perfectly normal and nothing to worry about? I'm not sure how to be more clear.

Comment: @Ali Not sure what that means, sorry -- are the requests coming from the router? Or are you suggesting they have a different origin? The web server is running on my machine.

Comment: @tylerl question edited, hopefully makes it more clear.